# get file content if file exists or default String

Tags: haskell, io

I check `doesFileExist filePath` but
how can i use `handle <- openFile filePath ReadMode` only when the file exists

Or how can i get a default string when file does not exist?

```
getFileContent filePath = do
    handle <- openFile filePath ReadMode
    content <- hGetContents handle
    return content

main = do
    blacklistExists <- doesFileExist "./blacklist.txt"
    let fileContent = if not blacklistExists
            then ""
            else getFileContent "./blacklist.txt"

    putStrLn fileContent
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Like this:

```
import Control.Exception

getFileContentOrElse :: String -> FilePath -> IO String
getFileContentOrElse def filePath = readFile filePath `catch`
    \e -> const (return def) (e :: IOException)

main = getFileContentOrElse "" "blacklist.txt" >>= putStrLn
```

The `const _ (e :: IOException)` bit is just to be able to give `e` a type annotation, so that `catch` knows which `Exception` instance to use.

Answer (score 4):

We can solve the *compiler error* as follows. The problem is that `getFileContent` is an `IO String` whereas `""` is just a `String`. We can use [**`return :: Monad m => a -> m a`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.11.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:return) to wrap data into for example an `IO`.

Then we still need to "unwrap the data the `IO String` carries when we want to print it, so we can change the `main` to:

```
main = do
    blacklistExists <- doesFileExist "./blacklist.txt"
    fileContent <- if not blacklistExists
            then return ""
            else getFileContent "./blacklist.txt"
    putStrLn fileContent
```

That being said the above is not very "safe". For example it could be possible that between checking the existance, and opening the file, somebody deletes the file. It is also possible that the file exists, but can not be read, etc.

It is thus better to use an "**E**asier to **A**sk **F**orgiveness than **P**ermission (EAFP)" approach where we aim to open the file, and if something goes wrong, we return the empty string, like proposed by [@DanielWagner](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51729478/67579).